# Recurly custom invoice fields

Tags: javascript, payment, invoice, recurly

Is it possible to add a custom field to Recurly Invoice or customize generated invoice in general?

For example, one would like to add a Reference text-field. So when the user checks out the order, he can insert Reference name and then it would be displayed at the generated invoice near billing details (company name, address).

Looks like Recurly API doesn't have tools for such customization, but still may be something was missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Recurly support it turned to be impossible at this point to modify the layout. The solution was to add custom Reference field to the PO-number.